# Create a square with additional data node data

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am pretty much a javascript noob, and very new to cytoscape (but i code in other languages)...

I am trying to use Cytoscape to graph out the servers available in my network. Creating a node per server and their relationship was straightforward actually.

I would like to add the possibility than when I click a node (let's say server12345) that it would open kind of a table with data associated with that server (servertype etc...).

Do you have any idea / examples / guidance on how I could:

1. add functionality on that click event of a specific node ?
2. how to create a 'details' table using cytoscope?

Thank you guys so much in advance!
(Ps: My first post on StackOverflow...)

Answer (score 3):

Nice question.

Firstly, you can capture the `click` event of cytoscape.js like below

```
cy.nodes().on('click', function(e){
  var clickedNode = e.target;
  console.log(clickedNode.id());
});
```

or you can also use the `tap` event of cytoscape.js

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
  var node = evt.target;
  console.log( 'tapped ' + node.id() );
});
```

You can read [events section of the documentation for more details](https://js.cytoscape.org/#events)

After you capture this event, I see to ways.

1-) Just modify an existing HTML element on the UI. For example in [here](https://ivis-at-bilkent.github.io/cytoscape.js-fcose/demo/demo-constraint.html) you can see on the left side there are some other elements.

So you can write your code like

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
  var node = evt.target;
  document.getElementById('someOtherElementOnUI').innerHTML = JSON.stringfy(node.data());
});
```

This will simply modify some other UI element (HTML element) and changes its content to the data of the selected node.

2-) You can use some extensions like [Cytoscape.js-popper](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper) and show data dynamically like a tooltip. You can check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66813720/3209523